# Pre-Populated Sqlite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Couple of people suggest me use  Sqlite Database if you want to ship large data  with application.I only find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database?lq=1) example for pre-populated data . I have some simple Questions

- this cause app to have two database .what can I do to remove one them ?
- what should be the extension of Pre-populated database file .txt, .db , .sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used pre-populated databases in my two applications,i use SQLiteAssetHelper and its quite helpful try it you won't regret.As far as the size goes i am not sure about it but i have used database of nearly 1mb quite easily with this.For SQLiteAssetHelper you will have to create zip file of your database and place it in databases folder under assests and give it a extension .db